# cpp: how to call another cpp .exe file in a cpp program

Tags: c++, windows

I am working on Windows system and I have already had an executable cpp program, in its file, there is an `a.exe` file.
Now I am coding another cpp program, and I want to execute the `a.exe` in this program.
Something like this:

```
void ExecuteA_exe()
{
     // some function to execute a.exe
}
```

I have tried the three functions: `WinExec`, `ShellExecute` and `CreateProcess`.
But I get the same result: Nothing ---- no error but no running `a.exe`.
My `a.exe` is just a simple cpp program, when I run it, I can get the console window. But If I run the second program, meaning that I try to call the function `ExecuteA_exe()` to run the `a.exe`, but I get nothing. I can't see the console window of `a.exe`.

Here is my little test:

```
int main()
{
    ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(), "open", "C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Documents\\bloomberg - api\\MarketDataAgent\\Debug\\MarketDataAgent.exe", "", "", SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, it will end without any error but also, no running `a.exe`. Anyway, I am waiting for the console of `a.exe` but I can't get it.

Comment: `\\` need to escape in string literal, otherwise you could use c++ raw string literal. You could use the errorcode returned by these apis to locate the error.

Comment: Also: check the return error code.

Comment: @Jichao   Yeah, I have reedited the question. Still, I can't get the console of `a.exe`.

Comment: You could run the other command using `system`

Comment: @MarcoA.    there is no error code man... my little test ends without any error. It seems that it ignores the `ShellExecute`.

Comment: error code is returned as int for `ShellExecute`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch    yeah but I don't want to use that. `system` takes lots of resources.

Comment: @Jichao   ah, alright, I try to catch it now.

Comment: @Jichao  I got it: 000002, it have checked it, 000002 means that "file name error". hmm.... for now I don't know why..

Comment: @Thomas: I don't know Windows (only using Linux or Unix since 1985), but I am curious why is `system` using *a lot* of resources on Windows?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  lol seriously I don't know either... When I was looking for something about the question "how to call .exe file in a cpp program", someone said that `system` was not good because It took many resources... Besides, I remembered that I read a book, and it said that to keep the console alive, we d better use `cin.get`, instead of `system`, because `system` took many resources.... See I don't know why, but people said that, so....

Comment: @Jichao   OK it's a stupid error. When I copied the path of the file name, somehow two spaces were added here "bloomberg - api"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a stupid question but I think it means something.
The third parameter of `ShellExecute()` is the path of executable file.
What I did is that I right clicked on the `a.exe` ---> properties ---> General ---> Location.
I just copied the "Location" to my cpp program.
But somehow two spaces were added before and after the `-', meaning that "bloomberg-api" became "bloomberg - api".
I don't know why.
Anyway...

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah   yeah, after removing the two spaces, everything works very well.